# Entry Tracker to see who has completed the course

Tags: craft3

I'm working on a project using Craft CMS for the first time, so far so good, however i'm stumped on how to do the following:

Create a button on each entry in a structure that states you have read the follow article. When you click you have read the article, it reflects on your account page that you have read the follow article(s).

Hopefully this makes sense, but it's almost like a LMS, you learn about something on the page you click you have completed the stage then move on to the next stage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd add an Entries field in your User field layout called `Articles Read` or such. Then whenever they click that they've read a particular article, I'd add the `id` of article entry that they've read to that field.

I'd do that probably via a custom plugin, but you could also do it with a simple form that passes the correct data to the the `actionUrl('users/save-user')` UsersController

Comment: how could i go about doing this inside the template file exactly? I've tried to use the save-user action url but when it submits it says they have read every article on the page rather than just the article they clicked they read (if this makes sense). I appreciate your help so far, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Andrews answer just a little example how to store information for a user via custom plugin. There are many resources how to create a plugin, [so [if] you wanna make a Craft 3 plugin](https://nystudio107.com/blog/so-you-wanna-make-a-craft-3-plugin) you should read those.

You form could look like this

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="plugin/controller/function">
    <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="1">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And your controller

```php
public function actionSave():Response
{
    $user = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity();
    if($user === null){
        // error, no user is logged in
        // handle it somehow
    }

    // check for a valid entry id
    $newId = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParam('entryId');
    if($newId === null){
        // error, no entry id provided...
    }

    // get the existing entries and add the new one to the array
    $existingIds = $user->getFieldValue('fieldHandle')->ids();
    $existingIds[] = $newId;

    // set the new value and store the element
    $user->setFieldValue('fieldHandle', $existingIds);
    if(!Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($user)){
        // could not save user due to validation errors, do something about it
    }

    // everything was successful, render a template or redirect or whatever you need
    return $this->renderTemplate('some/path', ['message' => 'hooooray']);
}
```

Comment: i created a plugin, but for some reason cannot hit that path to my controller with the function, it just tells me the page doesnt exist. any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing your code? No - but that's a different question, please visit slack to get in touch or ask a new question to keep everything clean

Comment: I actually got the correct value now and the form is submitting, however i created the field for the entry, but not sure what to do next. i was a bit unclear on addin the field to the user field or the entry field.

Comment: You should add the `entries` field to the user as @andrew.welch suggested. You can store every entry in your users.

Comment: I got exactly what i needed, however there's one more thing, on the return after the function runs, the redirect, i want to disable a button after submission that states they finished the course.